# Undo suggested edit which is already in pending review

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

I edited a post which was in need to have the code formatting fix, and at the same time the post's author fixed what I was fixing before I hit the *Save Edits* button!
Now my edit, which there is no need for, is in pending review.

So how can I remove suggested edit in pending review?

Comment: Long story short you can't but it's not that big a deal if it was a one-time mistake. Either flag it for moderator attention, explaining you changed your mind/there was an edit conflict, or just let it be rejected - if it's no better than the current version, it will be, and unless you have a significant amount of rejected edits, it shouldn't get you an edit ban nor rep loss.